# Weird CSS background image issue with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: css, firebase-storage

I have images stored in Google Cloud Storage and used in an Ionic / Angular app. The images are shown as a background of a div element. They're mostly showing ok but in some cases, the image is missing. And it's consistently specific images that are missing - not others - no matter how many times the pages are reloaded.

Right-clicking on the background image to get the background URL and then pasting that URL in the browser results in the image displaying fine.

The scss code contains the basics styling of the image and the background image URL is added inline within the HTML file.

item.scss

```
    offer {
    .card-image{
        background-color:lightgray; 
        background-position:center; 
        background-size:cover; 
        height:10rem; 
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

item.html

```
    <ion-card>
  <div class="card-image" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image' : 'url(' + offer?.imageUrl + ')' }"> 
  </div>
  <ion-item text-wrap>
    <h2 text-wrap>{{ offer?.name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ offer?.provider }}</p>
  </ion-item>
  <!--
  <ion-item>
    <span item-left>18 min</span>
    <span item-left>(2.6 mi)</span>
    <button ion-button icon-left clear item-end>
      <ion-icon name="navigate"></ion-icon>
      Start
    </button>
  </ion-item>
  -->
</ion-card>
```

And here's what it looks like rendered with the middle item's image absent...

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using for testing?

Comment: Chrome with the Dev console on on a mac

Comment: Sorry meant the developer inspector is open (prevents caching)

Comment: Did you try in other browsers? I apologize for the basic question, but whenever there are odd rendering problems, it's the equivalent of "Did you try turning it off and on again?"

Comment: Hey Aaron, it’s a good point. Been trying it on different browsers and devices yes. So safari and chrome on iOS and also chrome in normal and incognito modes on osx. Also the web app being also an ionic app is being rendered within a system browser within the context of an actual iOS app... behaviour remains the same

Comment: Instead of copy/pasting, did you try right-clicking on the URL in the DOM or Styles explorers and click open in new tab?

Comment: It's now resolved. Looks like there was a problem with URL escaping :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I see the problem. After a bit of head-scratching, it turns out that there was some error with escaping the URL of the background image. So any image with a space in its name was absent.

Solution: change the file names to avoid spaces or escape URL's. It's now working as expected!